# How do you fill an array with objects from a different class? deteils below

Tags: java, arrays

*"This question is for a free online course I am taking. Below is the instructors direction and below that is my answer. I must be solving the problem wrong because the automatic grading system marks it incorrect even though I got the correct output. I believe the instructor wanted me to fill an array in the Main class with objects from the person class and I am unsure how to do that. Please help if you know how to do that or if you have a better idea of what the instructor wanted."*

### Instructors direction

In your main method, make an array of type Person Fill it with Person objects of the following people and then print the names of each from that array. Each person should be on their own line formatted as shown below.

> Fred, 24
>
> Sally, 26
>
> Billy, 15

---

### main.java

```
class Main {

    public static Person[] people;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Person personObject = new Person();

       personObject.Person();

    }
}
```

### Person.java

```
public class Person{

    public static String[] Person(){

        String[] people = {"Fred, 24", "Sally, 26", "Billy, 15"};

        for(int i=0; i< people.length; i++){
            System.out.println(people[i]);
        }

        return people;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to take some time to read [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Methods should not be named starting with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says you need objects and array. So i guess you wanted something like this.

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {
private String name;
private int age;



public Person(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person{" + "name=" + name + ", age=" + age + '}';
}
}
```

By declaring `Person p1 = new Person("Sally",26);` you are creating object of class Person. You can use that as many times as you want and create different objects. We use override method toString to print informations about Person. We could also use `p1.getName()` and `p1.getAge()`

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



    Person p1 = new Person("Fred", 24);
    Person p2 = new Person("Sally", 26);
    Person p3 = new Person("Billy", 55);

    Person[] people = {p1,p2,p3};

    for(Person p : people){
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This works to get the output but I still haven't passed the assignment and I am still not sure exactly what the professor wants.

Comment: Change System.out.println(p.toString()); to System.out.println(p.getName() + “, “ + p.getAge());

Answer (score -1):

I think what your professor wants is something like this :)

```
public class Runner {


public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  

    Persons person1 = new Persons();
    Persons person2 = new Persons();
    Persons person3 = new Persons();

    person1.setName("Fred");
    person1.setAge("24");

    person2.setName("Sally");
    person2.setAge("26");

    person3.setName("Billy");
    person3.setAge("15");

    String[] list = {person1.toString(), person2.toString(), person3.toString()};
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }

}
```

}

```
public class Persons {
private String name;
private String age;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return  name + ", " + age;
}
```

}

Comment: This works to get the output but It still hasn't passed the assignment & I am clueless as to what the professor wants.